# postgresql group by sequence time stamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm about two weeks old in SQL years so if you could humor me a little it would be very helpful.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to `group by` a series of sequential timestamps (hour steps in this case).

```
For example:

ID          time
1           2008-11-11 01:00:00
2           2008-11-11 02:00:00
3           2008-11-11 04:00:00
4           2008-11-11 05:00:00
5           2008-11-11 06:00:00 
6           2008-11-11 08:00:00
```

I'd like to end up with grouping like so:

```
Group    above_table_ID's
1        1,2
2        3,4,5
3        6
```

This would be easy to express in the python loop or something but I really don't understand how to express this type of logic in sql/postgresql.

If anyone could help explain this process to me it would be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by subtracting an increasing number from the time stamps, in hours.  Things that are sequential will have the same value.

```
select row_number() over (order by grp) as GroupId,
       string_agg(id, ',') as ids
from (select t.*,
             (time - row_number() over (order by time) * interval '1 hour') as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: Gordon you have lead my to window functions and most likely changed my life. Thank you